# Entity Framework Triggering one additional query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I'm using **Entity Framework 6.1.3**. and The _repository object is a Extension of **IdentityDbContext**.

In the DBContext initialization I'm using the following configurations:

```
this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

The following code shows the unexpected behaviour:

```
var car = _repository.Set<Car>().AsQueryable().Where(s => s.Id == carID)
                .Include(s => s.Trunk)
                .FirstOrDefault();

car.Doors = _repository.Set<Door>().AsQueryable().Where(s => s.Car_Id == carID).Include(s => s.Window).ToList();

if(car.Doors.Any()) // Another Query is triggered Here!
{
   return;
}
```

In the above scenario, I try to Eager Load the **Doors** Collection of the **Car** entity by setting the **Doors** collection. However, when this collection is accessed another Query is triggered. I supposed that it's a problem with the Dynamic Proxy that EF is creating for the **car** entity:

- The getter of the proxy probably isn't checking if the collection is already loaded.
- Or maybe the setter of the proxy isn't setting the collection as Loaded. (The **_isLoaded** attribute of the System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.**RelatedEnd**)

Comment: The collection *isn't* loaded. You set it, but that's not the same as loading it. Either make sure it's loaded by EF (using `Include` or `Load`) or disable lazy loading and let relationship fixup do its job.

Comment: @GertArnold, I understand that, and one solution is to set the collection as loaded after setting it's value with '_context.Entry(objToInclude).Collection(includeCondition).IsLoaded = true;'

But I dont like this solution, cause all the other programmers must be warned to use it.